# Error #1065: Variable JSON is not defined. (Flash player 11.3 browser)

Tags: actionscript-3

My Actionscript application compiles and works fine offline. On my server I keep getting an

```
  Error #1065: Variable JSON is not defined
```

I'm running Flash player 11.3 (tested both on debug and otherwise) . If I remember correctly this used to be a Runtime error. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194112/referenceerror-error-1065-variable-json-is-not-defined help you!

Comment: yeah this should be swf-version >= 13

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fahim, I'm listing this here as a reference to the other answer. For this to work,

> -swf-version=13+

is required:

> FP 11.0 = 13 FP 11.1 = 14 FP 11.2 = 15 FP 11.3 = 16

Now, the reason why the above error comes is because if a preloader (app loading swf) is not compiled with FP 11 or the above directive, the loaded application's domain will also not have JSON defined. So if you receive that error, it is either the preloader swf or the loaded swf that was not compiled with correct Flash Player version.